# Scikit Learn Tree-based feature selection keeping the columns name?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

i want to make a selection of features tree-based. 
My dataset has about 30 columns and after doing, there are about 5. 
Which for me is great, the problem i have, is that the dataset of 5 columns that i get, does not keep the names of the columns and i can not identify them.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel

data = pd.read_csv(file)
X = data.drop('target', 1)
y = data['target']
X.shape                        #(100000, 30)
clf = ExtraTreesClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
clf.feature_importances_  

model = SelectFromModel(clf, prefit=True)
X_new = model.transform(X)
X_new.shape                    #(100000, 5)
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Try the [`get_support`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.get_support) feature. as in `model.get_support(indices=True)`

Comment: Hello ehudk, doing what you tell me, I get the column numbers of the original dataset selected. It is true that it does not indicate the name of the column, but it is a solution. I will leave open the question in case someone else wants to contribute. Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now when I'm more sure of the answer, please try the following:

`mask = model.get_support(indices=False)    # this will return boolean mask for the columns
X_new = X.loc[:, mask]                      # the sliced dataframe, keeping selected columns
featured_col_names = X_new.columns          # columns name index`

If all you need is just the column names:
`X.columns[model.get_support()]`

Comment: Thanks ehudk i will try!